# purrr over multiple groups of variables in R

Tags: r, function, iteration, mapping, purrr

I have a dataframe with many scales, and I want to calculate each participant's mean and sum as well as the grand mean and grand sum for **each scale**. I've can't figure out how to us pmap_dbl to get me my results. I've tried writing a function, but it's failed.

Here's a sample of the data:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(tep_1 = sample(c(0,1), 5, replace = TRUE),
             tep_2 = sample(c(0,1), 5, replace = TRUE),
             adarta_1 = sample(c(0,1), 5, replace = TRUE),
             adarta_2 = sample(c(0,1), 5, replace = TRUE),
             adarta_3 = sample(c(0,1), 5, replace = TRUE),
             adarta_4 = sample(c(0,1), 5, replace = TRUE),
             adarta_5 = sample(c(0,1), 5, replace = TRUE),
             adarta_6 = sample(c(0,1), 5, replace = TRUE))
```

Here's my function, which doesn't work. Note: This function only attempts to get the row sum, but I also need the row mean, mean, and standard deviation:

```
column_prefix <- c("tep", "adarta")

my_fun <- function(x, y) {
  x %>%
  select(starts_with(y)) %>%
    rowSums(x, na.rm = TRUE)
}

map2_dbl(.x = df, .y = column_prefix, .f = my_fun)

Error: Mapped vectors must have consistent lengths:
* `.x` has length 8
* `.y` has length 2
```

And I want to make it so I can get this output with that function:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>%
  mutate(tep_grand_mean = mean(c(tep_1, tep_2)),
         tep_sd = sd(tep_grand_mean),
         adarta_grand_mean = mean(c(adarta_1, adarta_1, adarta_2, adarta_3, adarta_4, adarta_5, adarta_6)),
         adarta_sd = sd(adarta_grand_mean),
         tep_sum = pmap_dbl(select(., starts_with("tep")), sum),
         tep_mean = rowMeans(select(., contains("tep")), na.rm = TRUE),
         adarta_sum = pmap_dbl(select(., starts_with("adarta")), sum),
         adarta_mean = rowMeans(select(., contains("adarta")), na.rm = TRUE))
~~~~~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, we may need only `map` after making some changes in the function

```
map(column_prefix, my_fun, x = df)
#[[1]]
#[1] 0 0 2 2 1

#[[2]]
#[1] 4 2 0 1 4
```

---

```
my_fun <- function(x, y) {
  x %>%
   select(starts_with(y)) %>%
    rowSums(na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

---

`map2` is used when the two objects have the same length or if one object is having a single element, wrap it with `list` and recycle

---

If we need the `mean` for each similar prefixed names.  One option is `split.default`

```
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    split.default(str_remove(names(.), "_\\d+$")) %>% 
    map_df(rowMeans)%>% 
    rename_all(~ str_c(., '_mean')) %>% 
    bind_cols(df, .)
# A tibble: 5 x 10
#  tep_1 tep_2 adarta_1 adarta_2 adarta_3 adarta_4 adarta_5 adarta_6 adarta_mean tep_mean
#* <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>
#1     0     1        0        0        0        0        0        1       0.167      0.5
#2     0     0        1        1        0        1        0        0       0.5        0  
#3     1     1        0        0        1        1        1        0       0.5        1  
#4     1     0        0        1        1        0        0        0       0.333      0.5
#5     1     0        1        1        1        1        0        0       0.667      0.5
```

---

Or we could make use of reshaping to 'long' format with `pivot_longer`

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_to = c('.value', 'group'), names_sep="_") %>% 
   group_by(rn) %>% 
   summarise_at(vars(tep, adarta), list(mean = ~mean(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
   select(-rn) %>%
   bind_cols(df, .)
# A tibble: 5 x 10
#  tep_1 tep_2 adarta_1 adarta_2 adarta_3 adarta_4 adarta_5 adarta_6 tep_mean adarta_mean
#* <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>
#1     0     1        0        0        0        0        0        1      0.5       0.167
#2     0     0        1        1        0        1        0        0      0         0.5  
#3     1     1        0        0        1        1        1        0      1         0.5  
#4     1     0        0        1        1        0        0        0      0.5       0.333
#5     1     0        1        1        1        1        0        0      0.5       0.667
```

In the newer version of `dplyr`, we can also use `across` with `summarise`

```
df %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_to = c('.value', 'group'), names_sep="_") %>% 
    group_by(rn) %>% 
    summarise(across(c(tep, adarta),  ~mean(., na.rm = TRUE), names = "{col}_mean" )) %>%
    select(-rn) %>%
    bind_cols(df, .)
# A tibble: 5 x 10
#  tep_1 tep_2 adarta_1 adarta_2 adarta_3 adarta_4 adarta_5 adarta_6 tep_mean adarta_mean
#* <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>
#1     0     1        0        0        0        0        0        1      0.5       0.167
#2     0     0        1        1        0        1        0        0      0         0.5  
#3     1     1        0        0        1        1        1        0      1         0.5  
#4     1     0        0        1        1        0        0        0      0.5       0.333
#5     1     0        1        1        1        1        0        0      0.5       0.667
```

Comment: thank you, akrun! Two follow up questions, what if I wanted to get the row sums and the row means? Is there a way to modify the function to give multiple outputs? Once I know that, I can do it on my own to get all the others. Second, is there a way I can get it to make the output a column? For instance, tep_mean, adarta_mean rather than [[1]] and [[2]]?

Comment: I added three  optioins.  Hopefully, it works for you